# Let $X$ be a compact set topological space, $Y$ be Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact set topological space, $Y$ be Hausdorff. Prove that if $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous,then it maps closed sets to closed sets.

What I think is choose any closed set $C$ in $X$,since $X$ is compact,then $C$ is also compact. Then $f(C)$ is closed in $Y$ since $Y$ is Hausdorff.

Is the proof correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. I would mention $f (C) $ is compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. But take the step first that $f[C]$ is compact, because $f$ is continuous. This should be explicit. And then invoke the theorem that a compact subset in a Hausdorff space is closed.